# How to edit views when waiting for a thread?

Tags: android, multithreading, view

I load my articles from my wordpress webpage. And want to display them in my app.
In order to be allowed to wait for a internet response I had to create a Thread.
Using this method:

```
private void loadArticles(final String url) {
    Thread thread = new Thread(new Runnable(){
        @Override
        public void run() {
            try {
                //Get my data and run createArticles();
            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    });

    thread.start();
}
```

Then in the createArticles function I try to use my function addViewToParent(...) and I get an error that says:

> Only the original thread that created a view hierarchy can touch its
>   views.

How can i work around this problem?

EDIT: I use these networking functions if it matters...

```
//Connect to the url
URL pageURL = new URL(url);
HttpURLConnection connection = (HttpURLConnection) pageURL.openConnection();
BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(
     new InputStreamReader(connection.getInputStream())
);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to modify your Views, e.g. show your article, you have to run the code on the UI/main thread. To achieve this, you could call run `runOnUiThread()` in your Activity:

```
private void loadArticles(final String url) {
    Thread thread = new Thread(new Runnable(){
        @Override
        public void run() {
            try {
                //Get my data ...

                runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                    public void run() {
                        // modify Views here
                        createArticles();
                    }
                });
            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    });

    thread.start();
}
```

Comment: I belive this works, thank you! Not the most intuitive way doing though =/

Answer (score 2):

You need to use function runOnUiThread. This is function for user interface thread.

```
private void loadArticles(final String url) {
    //Get my data ...

    runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
        public void run() {
        // modify Views here
             createArticles();
        }
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Just use a Handler instead, so you'll have access to the UI Thread:

```
new Handler().post(new Runnable(){
    @Override
    public void run() {
        try {
            //Get my data and run createArticles();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
});
```

Comment: Tried that, I'm back to getting: android.os.NetworkOnMainThreadException

Comment: That's another issue, you should probably use AsyncTask to get the data from your server.